# Ping server process is hanging

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to ping a server before uploading a file with ftp.  Recently, a client complained that the process was freezing.  I tested the ping process with a vbscript file just to make sure something wasn't broken on the computer.  The vbscript worked just fine.  So I ran the script from the Access database and it hung just the same as it did before.  Is there something about the ping exe that I am missing here?

Vbscript that runs just fine when you double click it.

```
Const fsoForWriting = 2

Dim oShell, ping, strPath, strPing
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set ping = oShell.exec("ping -n 2 -w 750 google.com")
Do While ping.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
strPing = ping.StdOut.ReadAll
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTextFile = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strPath) & "\PingResults.txt"
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile, fsoForWriting, True)
objTextStream.WriteLine strPing
objTextStream.Close
Set objTextStream = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set oShell = Nothing
```

VBA function that runs on the test database on startup.  This is the code that hangs.

```
Function fFtpOnline(ByVal ComputerName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim oShell, ping
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set ping = oShell.exec("cscript " & Access.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Test.vbs")
    Do While ping.Status = 0
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set oShell = Nothing

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " " & "fFtpOnline "
    Resume Next
End Function
```

This code works fine on my computer but on the client's computer, the code hangs.

Comment: Sounds like it might be more of a network configuration issue rather than something with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a rude answer, but by no means is it intended to be.  Just as the comment above stated, this is more than likely it issue on your customer's end.  If the program works currently on your end and not theirs they have the issue, not the code.  I've run into plenty of customers who are clueless so unless they are willing to let you take control of their machine remotely I would recommend them capturing some information for you.  ipconfig is a good place to start.  And while they are at the command prompt have them try to ping some places.  I know this is not a true answer, but it is what I have encountered in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think that since the vb script works just fine by itself, the network isn't the issue.  The problem comes up when I run the vbscript with Access.